# Deserializing JSON empty value Jakson java

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, jackson, jqwidget

I am using Spring 4 MVC, JQDataTable and Jaskon library to send JSON object from JSP to spring controller.

In table when i click save button i fire ajax call. Here is two senario.

1. My row may be old: In this case i have department Id and hibrnate saveoruupate command will update row.
2. My row may be new: In this case i won't have department id and hibernate saveorupdate command will save new row.
   Note:One controller for both operation.

when i click on update button, 
if row is old json object is `"{\"departmentId\":2,\"departmentName\":\"hmkcode\",\"createdBy\":1,\"modifiedBy\":1,\"status\":true}",` JSON object deserialise successfully and update command get fire successfully
if row is new json object is
`{\"departmentId\":,\"departmentName\":\"hmkcode\",\"createdBy\":1,\"modifiedBy\":1,\"status\":true}",` in this case my department id is empty and so JSON object dont get parse and give error.

I know i have to handle it in javascript to exclude department id tag if it is new row. 
There will be lots of master in application so every time i have to handle in javascript. Javascript increase code.
Is there any way to handle in corresponding Java model. I have initialize value to zero still i gives parsing error.
Additionally: i have to add new command property in Java model. if row is new or department id is 0 then automatically command property set to "ADD" and if row is old, department id is not zero then set command property to "UPADATE".

```
 updateRow: function (rowID, rowData, commit) {
                var jsonToBeSend="{\"departmentId\":"+rowData.departmentId+",\"departmentName\":\""+rowData.departmentName+"\",\"createdBy\":1,\"modifiedBy\":1,\"status\":"+rowData.status+"}";

                alert(dept)
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "/BusinessReimbursment/addDepartment", 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    data: jsonToBeSend,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    mimeType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) { 
                        alert(data.success + " " + data.message);
                        commit(true);
                    },
                    error:function(data) { 
                       // alert("error: "+data);
                       // $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('deleteRow', rowID);
                    }
                });

public class DepartmentDTO implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Integer departmentId=0;

@NotNull
@Size(min=3,max=30,message="Department lenght should be between 3 to 30 character")
String departmentName;

Integer createdBy;

Integer modifiedBy;
@NotNull
Boolean status;
}
```

@controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addDepartment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody AjaxResponse addDepartment(@RequestBody final DepartmentDTO departmentDTO){
        AjaxResponse response=new AjaxResponse();
        Department department=DepartmentConvertor.setDepartmentDTOToDepartment(departmentDTO);
        if(Validation.validateForNullObject(department)){
            departmentService.addDepartment(department);
        }
        response.setSuccess(Boolean.TRUE);
        response.setMessage("Record save Successfully");
        return response;
    }
```

One more stupid question. in model should i use primitive variable or wrapper classes variable?? Same question in hibernate model.

if u know JQ Widget then: can i convert datarow to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {\"departmentId\":,\"departmentName\":\"hmkcode\",\"createdBy\":1,\"modifiedBy\":1,\"status\":true}",
>   in this case my department id is empty and so JSON object dont get
>   parse and give error.

because of `departmentId` doesn't have a value, set `null` or `''` empty value in this case to parse JSON successfully.

```
updateRow: function (rowID, rowData, commit) {
                var jsonToBeSend = new Object();
                if (rowData.departmentId != "" || rowData.departmentId != null){
                 jsonToBeSend["departmentId"] = rowData.departmentId;
                }
                jsonToBeSend["departmentName"] = rowData.departmentName;
                jsonToBeSend["createdBy"] = 1;
                jsonToBeSend["modifiedBy"] = 1;
                jsonToBeSend["status"] = rowData.status;
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "/BusinessReimbursment/addDepartment", 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsonToBeSend),
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {                 
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    }
                    success: function(data) { 
                        alert(data.success + " " + data.message);
                        commit(true);
                    },
                    error:function(data) { 
                       // alert("error: "+data);
                       // $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('deleteRow', rowID);
                    }
                });
```

> in model should i use primitive variable or wrapper classes
>   variable?? Same question in hibernate model.

Prefer Wrapper classes, in primitive variable you cannot store null value. also change below statement in DTO class

from:

```
Integer departmentId=0;
```

to:

```
Integer departmentId;
```

New department model classes which are not saved should have `null` ID.